# Access the certain instance of parent's class calling relation's method from inside of the method

Tags: relationship, laravel-5.4

It's no relevant question and there are a lot of workarounds, but I've come to an interesting point, asking myself the following question:
Let's say I have an `User` and a `Comment` models, connected via a `HasMany` relation.

```
    $user = App\User::first(); //his name is John
    $user->name = 'George';
    $user->comments()->first()->myMethod();

    //inside of Comment model
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $userInstanceThatCalledMe = $this->user; //that's loading the record from the database again, but we want the exact same instance, that called the method
        //aaaand $user->name would still return 'John' instead of George. 
    }
```

I know I can pass a lot of the stuff as function arguments, but I'd like to know if laravel provides some kind of way to access the exact same parent instance trough the child's method. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a known issue that's supposed to be fixed in L5.4. github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9355

Comment: @Axalix I am using Laravel 5.4, did you mean 5.5?

Comment: I saw your tag, but I am not sure you have the most up to date version of L5.4. What I mean is this http://c2n.me/3MTU6un.png And yes, try 5.5 - just to be sure.

Comment: @Axalix I'm currently using 5.4.17, atleast according to composer

Comment: The latest is 22 https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases#laravel-5.4.22

Comment: Would there be a way to update it via composer without updating anything else? Because last time I tried updating composer just updated everything and the site was not working at all.